# Excel SUM Function, replacing preformed formula to include value of a certain cel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, sum

ok i have the following formula on my "Overall" WorkSheet

```
SUM(Friday::'Register 2016-17'::W6:Z6)
```

which works well

however i don't want to have a static cell range for which to count, so i have a cell on my "Overall" WorkSheet (for ease lets say it is cell A1) which contains a reference of cells, something like CC:CF

What i want to do is modify the above formula so that it replaces the W6:Z6 with the value of the cell A1

so i thought this would be easy and have tried this

```
SUM(Friday::'Register 2016-17'::A1)
```

Hoping the A1 cell reference would add in the correct cell range stored in cell A1, unfortunately it only resulted in an error,

Can someone show me the error of my way please
Many thanks

Comment: Look into INDIRECT()

Comment: Is `SUM(Friday::'Register 2016-17'::W6:Z6)` literally the formula that you're using? If so ....it works?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes it works but I'm trying to replace the Value W6:Z6 with the value stored in cell A1 which is another 2 cell combination, its when i try and include the cell reference in the above formula that it breaks

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you that looks promising, will have a play with it and see if i can get it working, thanks

Comment: ...woah, I've never seen a formula formatted like that. I'll have to look in to what that is doing.  [Neat!](https://i.imgur.com/iYOXpB3.gif)

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks :) i think scott is on the right tracks with INDIRECT but as of yet I'm having no luck using it within the formula

Comment: I would not know where to start as `::` is a custom format that I have never seen before.

Comment: @ScottCraner that's what I was thinking/hoping. I almost would want to open *that* as a question, but have no idea how to even use it to give an example!

Comment: Try doing `SUM(Friday::'Register 2016-17'::Indirect(A1))`

Comment: @BruceWayne returns a "this formula contains a syntax error" error, i think it is close, just need this bit Indirect(A1) to somehow return the cell value. I've tried just indirect(a1) and get same error but when typing indirect("a1") it returns the value i want, so you would of thought `code`SUM(Friday::'Register 2016-17'::Indirect("A1")) would work but nope still says has a syntax error.

Comment: seemed to of solved it? need to test it out more tho, seems the issue was i was not referencing the row number in my cell range in A1 where as i had CC::CF i should of had CC5::CF5, it seems to be working... with a few hacks lol

Comment: What does `::` mean? What version of Excel? I tried in version 2010 and it comes up with an error msgbox.